# Type 'string' is not assignable to type [object]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have an interface as follows:

```
interface Order {
 symbol: string
 side: string
 price: number
 quantity: number
}
```

I have a line in my code where I am accessing values in a table. However, it complains and says that d.symbol is not assignable to a string.

```
accessor:  (d: Order) : Order  =>  d.symbol
```

Does anyone know how I can work around this?

Comment: Please have a look at this [help topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on how to create a "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example". This question is at high risk for deletion.

Comment: Rolled back to original revision, to lower risk of deletion...

Comment: There is easily enough information in this question for it to be answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(d: Order) : Order  =>  d.symbol
```

This line means "A function accepting one argument (`d`) of type `Order` that **returns** an `Order`".

Your function returns a `string`, not an `Order`.

You can fix the return type annotation

```
(d: Order) : string  =>  d.symbol
```

Or remove it

```
(d: Order) =>  d.symbol
```

Or return the correct kind of thing, if that's what was actually intended

```
(d: Order) : Order  =>  d
```

Answer (score 0):

You returned a string when you declared that the return type is `Order`.

Solution: change the return type to `string`.

Comment: This is not always an option in dynamic systems.